Journals for expository papers in theoretical computer science?
Is there a suitable venue to publish compilations of old results in TCS? (More specifically, in my case, "logic in computer science", but I am also curious about answers concerning algorithms/complexity/etc.)
This is basically the same question as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work except the answers therein are all about pure math and don't seem well-suited to TCS.
